# Separation of variables for wave equation's boundary-value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation

I am hoping to receive some thoughts on an analytical solution of the following equation, 
$$ u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\gamma u, $$
for $x\in (0,L)$ and $t\in (0,\infty)$, with initial conditions
$$ u(0,x)=0, \qquad u_t(0,x)=0,$$
and boundary conditions
$$ u(t,0)=f(t), \qquad u_x(t,L)+cu(t,L)=g(t),$$
where $\gamma$ and $c$ are known constants.

I have tried separation of variables, $u=T(t)X(x)$, but obtain only a trivial solution for $T$.

Comment: What did you expect? If there is no initial wave, what would cause one?

Answer (score 1):

Using separation of variables $u(x,t) = X(x) T(t)$, we have
$$
\frac{T''}{T} = \frac{X''}{X} + \gamma = -\lambda \, ,
$$
i.e.
$$
{T''} + \lambda T = 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad
{X''} + (\lambda-\gamma) X = 0
$$
for which the Fourier series approach could be applied. However, this might not be an easy task in the case where the boundary conditions are time-dependent.

The problem at hand is very similar to those of a one-dimensional string with vibrating ends. A possible strategy would consist in searching the solution as a sum of eigenfunctions -- so-called normal mode decomposition or expansion. To find the normal modes, one solves the same problem with homogeneous boundary conditions ($f=0$, $g=0$), see e.g. [this link](http://yfaat.ch.huji.ac.il/mark/vib.php) and chap. 4 of (1). Note that [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3302106/418542) is closely related.

Alternatively, one may use the method of characteristics for the system
$$
\begin{aligned}
u_t \qquad &= v\\
\varepsilon_t -v_x &= 0\\
v_t - \varepsilon_x &= \gamma u
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\varepsilon = u_x$, but this might not be straightforward due to the right-hand side. You may have a look at (1), chap. 12.

Lastly, one may solve the problem by using Laplace transforms (see e.g. chap. 13 of (1)).

---

(1) R. Habermann, *Applied Partial Differential Equations with Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems*, 5th ed. Pearson Education Inc., 2013.

Comment: Dear Harry49, thank you for the response.  It was informative and helpful.